# Exception handling using Lambda in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I'm doing some tests using lambda expressions but my code does not compile. My lambda implementation is wrong or the exception handling? What would be the correct implementation of the following code?

```
class MyObject { }

interface Creatable<T> {
    T create() throws IOException;
}

/* Using the code: */
Creatable<MyObject> creator = () ->  {
    try {
        return new MyObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

MyObject obj1 = creator.create();
```

If i remove the try catch block and declare the exception to throw in the method, the code compiles and runs normally.

```
Creatable<MyObject> creator = () -> new MyObject();
```

The compilation error is:

`incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression`

Comment: This actually doesn't have much to do with the lambda. The same method body won't compile if you declare it the normal way. The error message just isn't particularly informative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your lambda needs to return a `MyObject`. If the `try` block completes successfully that is the case, but if it doesn't the `catch` block is executed which does not return anything. So you could write:

```
Creatable<MyObject> creator = () ->  {
    try {
        return new MyObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
};
```

But then you will get another compile error: "IOException is never thrown in try block". So you would also need to have a constructor in `MyObject` that throws an `IOException`:

```
class MyObject { MyObject() throws IOException {} }
```

In the end, unless `MyObject` actually throws an exception, you can simply use:

```
Creatable<MyObject> creator = () -> new MyObject();
```

which you can also write:

```
Creatable<MyObject> creator = MyObject::new;
```

Comment: Even if `new MyObject()` theos an exception, you can write it like that. In any case, the user of this interface must be prepared to get an `IOException` out of it. That's the point of implementing the interface in exactly this way.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda needs all paths to return the value as mentioned in the previous answer the easy solution is to return at the end of the catch block

However there is a more elegant way to handle exception when using lambda

you can wrap a lambda with another 
Example
wrap(((x,y)->x/y))

```
Biconsumer<Integer,Integer> consumer wrap(Biconsumer<Integer,Integer> consumer)    
{    
return (v,k)->{try

{consumer.apply()}

catch(){};

}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLKMCPMLv60&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTa9YGfyhyW2CqdtW9RtY-I3&index=18

Answer (score 0):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CreateThrowable<T, R, E extends Throwable> {
   R create(T t) throws E;
static <T, R, E extends Throwable> Function<T, R> uncheckedException(ThrowingFunction<T, R, E> f) {
    return t -> {
        try {
            return f.create(t);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

}